# How do you use hash in URL to open a tab?

Tags: javascript, hash

I am having an issue opening tabs using the hash from the url.

Thats what I have right now:
https://web.njit.edu/~cpd5/tablinks/tabs.html

```
var open = window.location.hash.substr(1);

if(window.location.hash) {
    document.getElementById("open").click();
} 
else {
    document.getElementById("a").click();
}
```

If there is no # in the URL, the website works as it should but if it loads with a #, then all tabs open and the links don't work (the ids of the 3 tabs are a, b, and c).

ex. https://web.njit.edu/~cpd5/tablinks/tabs.html#b

Comment: Take a look at the Developers Tools console, you have errors you need to fix

Comment: can you post your htnl and complete script? what is the use of `open ` var here